# Magento 2 server and client-side validation

Tags: magento2, checkout, custom, security, validation

In [this Magento 2 documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_order.html) has provided tutorial how to create custom client-side validation before order placement, but does the validation not supposed to be in server-side also?

If the tutorial is incomplete then how to validate custom fields added to checkout page in server-side?
Example: when creating custom checkout field, the data from it is inserted into next db tables sales_order, sales_order_grid, quote. Is server-side validation even then necessary to add if i have followed this tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for client side validation, I have used class-

```
    <div class="wk-mp-design">
    <fieldset class="fieldset info wk-mp-fieldset">
        <legend class="legend">
            <span><?php echo __('Quote Request') ?></span>
        </legend>
  <form action="<?php echo $block->getUrl('quote/contact/save', ['_secure' => $this->getRequest()->isSecure()]) ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="quote-request" data-form="quote-request" data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}' data-hasrequired="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('* Required Fields') ?>">
            <div class="field required">
                <label class="label"><?php echo __('Full Name') ?>:</label>
                <div class="control">
                        <input type="text" id="full_name" name="full_name" title="Full Name" class="input-text" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field required">
                <label class="label"><?php echo __('Street Address') ?>:</label>
                <div class="control">
                        <input type="text" id="street_address" name="street_address" title="Street Address" class="input-text" class="input-text" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field required">
                <label class="label"><?php echo __('Suburb') ?>:</label>
                <div class="control">
                        <input type="text" id="district" name="district" title="Suburb" class="input-text" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field required">
                <label class="label"><?php echo __('Post Code') ?>:</label>
                <div class="control">
                        <input type="text" id="post_code" name="post_code" title="Post Code" class="input-text" class="input-text" class="input-text" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}"  />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field required">
                <label class="label"><?php echo __('Phone Number') ?>:</label>
                <div class="control">
                        <input type="text" id="phone_number" name="phone_number" title="Phone Number" class="input-text" class="input-text" class="input-text" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-number':true}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field required">
                <label class="label"><?php echo __('Email Address') ?>:</label>
                <div class="control">
                        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" title="Email Address" class="input-text" class="input-text" class="input-text" class="input-text" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field required">
                <?php echo __("Please attach any photo's that will help describe your job.(Max 5 images/3Mb of data. JPGS Only)") ?>
                <div class="control">
                        <input type="file" id="attachment" name="attachment"  title="Attachment" class="input-text" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field required">
                <div class="control">
                    <textarea name="description" id="description" class="input-text" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
              <button class="button wk-mp-btn" title="<?php echo __('Submit') ?>" type="submit" id="submit-btn">
                <span><span><?php echo __('Submit') ?></span></span>
            </button>
              <button class="button wk-mp-btn" title="<?php echo __('Reset') ?>" >
                <span><span><?php echo __('Reset') ?></span></span>
            </button>
        </form>
    </fieldset>
</div>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#quote-request": {
            "validation": {}
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: for phone_number 'validate-number':true is not working